# Argument #3 ($attribute) must be of type string, int given

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm trying to pass some data through requestBody with API Platform from my React code to my PHP code but I cannot fix the error I get :

> "@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
> "@type": "hydra:Error",
> "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
> "hydra:description": "ApiPlatform\Serializer\AbstractItemNormalizer::canAccessAttributePostDenormalize(): Argument #3 ($attribute) must be of type string, int given, called in /var/www/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php on line 365",

The json data that I try to pass looks like this, and I cannot see any int in there, I converted everything to String because I thought it was the problem but looks like it's not...

> [{"queue":"/api/queues/5","nbClients":"9","nbProcess":"5","nbCluster":"1","nbThreads":"6","studyId":"295"},{"queue":"/api/queues/5","nbClients":"9","nbProcess":"5","nbCluster":"1","nbThreads":"6","studyId":"296"},{"queue":"/api/queues/4","nbClients":"9","nbProcess":"24","nbCluster":"3","nbThreads":"6","studyId":"297"},{"queue":"/api/queues/5","nbClients":"9","nbProcess":"5","nbCluster":"1","nbThreads":"6","studyId":"298"},{"queue":"/api/queues/5","nbClients":"undefined","nbProcess":"undefined","nbCluster":"undefined","nbThreads":"undefined","studyId":"299"}]

Any idea of what the problem might be ?

Comment: There's a very similar thread about it [here](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/5464). If I'm understanding things correctly, it is because of an extra property being passed, one that doesn't exist on the entity.

Comment: _"Any idea of what the problem might be?"_: My educated guess is the input data: Number encoded as property/attribute name. You should refuse all JSON Text with JSON Strings that start with one or more digits on the left hand side of the colon ":" next to the empty string "". Otherwise it may happen that server subroutines are not able to process the influx in a safe and stable manner. Like throwing exceptions from deep inside. Give back a 400 Bad Request or 500 Internal Server Error. 500 if you think it is an error, 400 if you think it's the request that is in error.

Comment: If you have a typed datastructure you should have look there.